# Angular UI Router can't resolve state when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

as stated above in the title, I'm having difficulties with routing.

My route works, it just doesn't when the page reloads?

The routes object:

```
  {
    state: 'locations',
    config: {
      parent: 'root',
      url: '/locations',
      abstract: true,
      template: 
        '<!-- // LOCATIONS START // -->' +
        '<div data-ui-view></div>' +
        '<!-- // LOCATIONS END // -->'
    }
  },
  {
    state: 'locations.manageLocation',
    config: {
      url: '/manage/customer-details',
      templateUrl: 'platform/app/locations/locations.manage-location.html',
      controller: 'LocationsManageController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      title: 'Locations - Loading',
      params: {
        id: null
      },
      requires: {
        login: true,
        params: {
        storage: {
          id: 'campaignId'
        },
        values: ['id']
      }
    }
  }
```

Link to route:

```
<a data-ui-sref="locations.manageLocation({ id: customer.id })" class="button" href="#/locations/manage/customer-details">Manage Locations</a>
```

The actual error logged in the console is:
`Could not resolve 'undefined' from state ''`.

I'm confused on why this is, thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel dumb, I forgot to set the `customer.id` in localStorage, so the route wouldn't work on reload without the ID.